# Statamic: what is the reason to use antlers vs blade?

Tags: laravel, statamic

I did a little bard component using a blade file
I was able to access the bard fields e.g.

```
{{ $myField }}
```

instead of doing the antler way of

```
{{ block:myField }}
```

what functionality will be missing if I generally decide to use blade?
what other "bad surprises" will there be?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very good comparison: https://rias.be/blog/using-laravel-blade-with-statamic

I am new to statamic as well, but from what I've read so far you can easily use both engines. However antlers will give you more options out of the box (modifiers, directives) and will also give the the "template injected into layout" behavior of statamic.

If you want to use blade, there is a package that will allow you to use blade directives: https://github.com/edalzell/statamic-blade

More details on: https://statamic.dev/template-engines

Answer (score 0):

For anyone seeing this in the future: Statamic 3.3 is being released in a few days which will introduce [im](https://github.com/statamic/cms/pull/5238)[pro](https://github.com/statamic/cms/pull/5201)[vem](https://github.com/statamic/cms/pull/5058)[ents](https://github.com/statamic/cms/pull/5056) to Blade in Statamic and includes a [complete rewrite of Antlers](https://github.com/statamic/cms/pull/4257).